# How to get calculate ratio and compare between two

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I am making report, I need help finding who performed best.

I have 3 workers, and they are assigned number of work/task to do.

but but tasked assigned to each of them are not same numbers.

How can I find out who performed best (I was thinking calculating ratio or something)

**Employee John.**

```
He was given total 17 work orders but only 12 of them finished.
```

**James**

```
was given total 206 work order but only 117 of them finished.
```

**Nick**

```
was given 5 work order but only 3 of the finished.
```

How can I calculate who performed best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Find the percent of the completion of the work

John: $\dfrac{12}{17}.100=70.588$%

James:$\dfrac{117}{206}.100=56.796$%

Nick: $\dfrac{3}{5}.100=60$%

Now compare!

Comment: Thanks, what if they didn't complete any of the task ? meaning 0 of them.

Comment: for example for 4th person Jack, was assigned 9 task this month and he completed 0 of them so his % will be `0%` and next month Jack will get assigned 0 tasked and he ofcourse completed 0 of them. how can I compare last month task with this month if both are 0.